# SELECT @@ IDENTITY using SQL Server CE from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce

Im using Data Adapter/Set in SQL CE, i do create the following query to insert into table and then SELECT @@IDENTITY,
I want this SELECT statement return me the Student ID each time after Inserting into table, here is my Query:

```
INSERT INTO [Student] ([Name], [Family], [Address], [Phonenumber])
VALUES(@Name,@Family,@Address,@Phonenumber);
SELECT  @@IDENTITY;
```

here is how i call query:

```
int x = da.Insert("Albert", "Alexandra", "No4.Oxford", Telnum);
```

Int x suppose to return me ID...

Here is the Error im getting :

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 4,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = SELECT ]

Insert Query it self it works but once adding `SELECT @@ IDENTITY` at the end im getting error.

I really don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need something like  `SELECT ID AS LastID FROM Student WHERE ID = @@Identity;` take a look at this link as well [Server @@Identity](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Do you call `select @@ identity` or `select @@identity`? First will throw an error, second will work.

Comment: See this blog post from beth Massi: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/09/15/inserting-master-detail-data-into-a-sql-server-compact-edition-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The return value of *ExecuteNonQuery* will be number of rows effected by these query. so you need to use store procedure instead of Single Query.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/5f3eaed0-affb-43c5-894e-74191a9779db/), CE doesn't support multiple commands per execution and you need to do this as two commands synchronously.

Comment: I think you are right about it! because individually i can retrieve the last ID but once im combine them im getting Error! Thats sort of Weakness of SQL CE! but i need to be sure if really thats a case!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do this in a single call, you need to use a stored procedure rather than  `Insert`, because it uses `ExecuteNonQuery`, which does not return any records.  Otherwise you'll need to perform a select in another call to determine the identity.

The return value of [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) is an integer that denotes the number of rows affected by your call.